# Creating a class that inherits from other class classmethod

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, aws-cdk

so I'm trying to make in python a class named `DatabaseFromIdentifier` that inherits from DatabaseInstance but my issue is that I cannot run `super().__init__()` instead I need to do the same but using the `DatabaseInstance` classmethod `from_database_instance_attributes`. I tried `super().from_database_instance_attributes(...)` but this doesn't work as expected so I was wondering if its possible?

Some code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
class DatabaseFromIdentifier(rds.DatabaseInstance):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, identifier: str):
        self._identifier = identifier

        super().__init__(scope=scope,id=id)

        # Load Resources
        self._load_database_data()

        super().from_database_instance_attributes(
            scope=self,
            id="Database",
            instance_endpoint_address=self._endpoint_address,
            instance_identifier=self._identifier,
            port=self._port,
            security_groups=self._security_groups,
        )

        # Create/Load Resources
        self._secret = self._load_secret()
```

The classmethod:

```
@jsii.member(jsii_name="fromDatabaseInstanceAttributes")
    @builtins.classmethod
    def from_database_instance_attributes(
        cls,
        scope: _constructs_77d1e7e8.Construct,
        id: builtins.str,
        *,
        instance_endpoint_address: builtins.str,
        instance_identifier: builtins.str,
        port: jsii.Number,
        security_groups: typing.Sequence[_ISecurityGroup_acf8a799],
        engine: typing.Optional[IInstanceEngine] = None,
        instance_resource_id: typing.Optional[builtins.str] = None,
    ) -> IDatabaseInstance:
        '''Import an existing database instance.

        :param scope: -
        :param id: -
        :param instance_endpoint_address: The endpoint address.
        :param instance_identifier: The instance identifier.
        :param port: The database port.
        :param security_groups: The security groups of the instance.
        :param engine: The engine of the existing database Instance. Default: - the imported Instance's engine is unknown
        :param instance_resource_id: The AWS Region-unique, immutable identifier for the DB instance. This identifier is found in AWS CloudTrail log entries whenever the AWS KMS key for the DB instance is accessed.
        '''
        if __debug__:
            type_hints = typing.get_type_hints(_typecheckingstub__e84e286636afa00f9c760ec79c7dac8e6bb0eca8b8b9a221372c32480a5ec31b)
            check_type(argname="argument scope", value=scope, expected_type=type_hints["scope"])
            check_type(argname="argument id", value=id, expected_type=type_hints["id"])
        attrs = DatabaseInstanceAttributes(
            instance_endpoint_address=instance_endpoint_address,
            instance_identifier=instance_identifier,
            port=port,
            security_groups=security_groups,
            engine=engine,
            instance_resource_id=instance_resource_id,
        )

        return typing.cast(IDatabaseInstance, jsii.sinvoke(cls, "fromDatabaseInstanceAttributes", [scope, id, attrs]))
```

This is all part of the aws cdk python3 library.